# HashMap cannot be cast

Tags: java

I get the following error from the source below. Can anybody help?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap
```

I think the problem is in the line:

```
TreeMap functionResources = (TreeMap) ((Map) 
            AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)).get(function);
```

---

```
public abstract class AbstractParameterManager implements ParameterManager {
    protected static final Map resourceLocations = 
        ResourceLocator.locateResources();
    protected static final Map resources = new TreeMap();
    protected final Map overrides = new TreeMap();


    protected static Object getResource(String resourceId) {
        Map resourceMap = (Map) resources.get(resourceId);
        if (resourceMap == null) {
            resourceMap = new TreeMap();
            resources.put(resourceId, resourceMap);
        }
        return resourceMap;
    }

    protected static Map getResource(String resourceId, String function) {
        TreeMap functionResources = (TreeMap) ((Map) 
                AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)).get(function);
        if (functionResources == null) {
            functionResources = new TreeMap();
            ((Map) 
                      AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)).put(function, 
                      functionResources);
        }
        return functionResources;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you care that it's specifically a `TreeMap`? Why will a normal `Map` not do?

Comment: wow don't use Raw type, what is in your map, you need to specify !

Comment: Somehow, somewhere, the `resources` static variable gets a `HashMap` as a value. It isn't in the code you posted, so it must be elsewhere.

Comment: I hope this is really ancient (Java 1.4 or earlier) code.  It uses raw types everywhere.  Also, do you understand that `getResource()` discards the contents of `resources` except for one key every time it is called? The second time you call it (with a key different from the first time) it returns the value from the previous call.  I don't know what you're trying to do, but the code is seriously broken.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to cast a TreeMap to a HashMap.
You should follow a general guideline in which you first check whether the reference variable is of specific type, and only then perform cast.

Generally speaking, we do a cast from a supertype in the hierarchy to a sub-type to use specific methods provided by sub-type.

So here in this case you can cast TreeMap to a Map, or a HashMap to a Map, but the cast from TreeMap to HashMap or vice versa is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to typecast the Map as a TreeMap, you can just pass the map as a parameter when instantiating the TreeMap.

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("a", "a");
    hashMap.put("c", "c");
    hashMap.put("b", "b");
    Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);
    treeMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + " | " + v);
    });
}
```

output:

```
a = a
b = b
c = c
```

In your case, you'd have to replace the following line:

```
TreeMap functionResources = (TreeMap)((Map)AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)).get(function);
```

by

```
Map functionResources = new TreeMap((Map)AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)).get(function);
```

---

Now that the issue has been answered, there's a few more issues with your code. Your method `getResource` always return a map, and even if it doesn't, you'd have another error when you typecast `AbstractParameterManager.getResource(resourceId)` as a map. I strongly suggest that you change the return type of `getResource` to Map.

Answer (score 0):

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    hashMap.put("a", "a");
    hashMap.put("c", "c");
    hashMap.put("b", "b");
    Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(hashMap);

    treeMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
        System.out.println(k + " | " + v);
    });

}
```

@TwiN Error in initialization of the map